# Insert data into MySQL table from Python script

Tags: python, mysql

I have a MySQL Table named TBLTEST with two columns ID and qSQL. Each qSQL has SQL queries in it.

I have another table FACTRESTTBL.

There are 10 rows in the table TBLTEST.

For example, On TBLTEST lets take id =4 and qSQL ="select id, city, state from ABC".

How can I insert into the FACTRESTTBL from TBLTEST using python, may be using dictionary?

Thx!

Comment: You want to execute the query in column `qSQL` and insert the result into `FACTRESTTBL`? What are the columns of `FACTRESTTBL`?

Comment: Columns in FACTRESTTBL are id, city

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use [MySQLdb for Python](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_database_access.htm).

Sample code (you'll need to debug it as I have no way of running it here):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import MySQLdb

# Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","testuser","test123","TESTDB" )

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()

# Select qSQL with id=4.
cursor.execute("SELECT qSQL FROM TBLTEST WHERE id = 4")

# Fetch a single row using fetchone() method.
results = cursor.fetchone()

qSQL = results[0]

cursor.execute(qSQL)

# Fetch all the rows in a list of lists.
qSQLresults = cursor.fetchall()
for row in qSQLresults:
    id = row[0]
    city = row[1]

    #SQL query to INSERT a record into the table FACTRESTTBL.
    cursor.execute('''INSERT into FACTRESTTBL (id, city)
                  values (%s, %s)''',
                  (id, city))

    # Commit your changes in the database
    db.commit()

# disconnect from server
db.close()
```

Comment: There's also https://github.com/petehunt/PyMySQL, which is pure python if that matters for distribution purposes.

Comment: Given query works.

Since there are 10 rows in TBLTEST and above query runs if I am trying to execute 1 query at a time.

I want to execute multiple queries, say: cursor.execute("SELECT qSQL FROM TBLTEST WHERE id in(4, 5, 6)"), 

for id=5, qSQL="select id, city, zip from DEF"

for id=6, qSQL="select id, city, county from ABC"

How would you do that?

Thx