# Python Error connecting with MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

1. I am getting error message when I have con.close()- mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
2. I am getting error message when I remove con.close()- mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'localhost:3306', system error: 10054

Any suggestion? Thx
Below is my query:

```
import mysql.connector
class databaseConnection:
    def __init__ (self,settings ): 
        cur=settings.cursor()

        selectstmt=("SELECT qSQL FROM TBLTEST WHERE id = 4")
        cur.execute(selectstmt)
        res=cur.fetchone()
        qSQL=res[0]
        cur.execute(qSQL)
        qSQLresults=cur.fetchall()
        for row in qSQLresults:
            id= row[0]
            city= row[1]
            state=row[2]
            insertstmt=("""INSERT into FACTRESTTBL (id, city, state) 
                           values (%d, '%s', '%s')""" % (id, city, state))
            cur.execute(insertstmt)
            con.commit() 
        con.close() # 

print 'done'

con=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", 
                            user="root", 
                            password="test", 
                            database="test")
databaseobject = databaseConnection(con)
```

--

Comment: Shouldn't it be `settings.close()`?

Comment: Aside: you should pass the parameters as a second argument to `.execute()` to guard against SQL-injection attack.

Comment: I did similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14863692/insert-data-into-mysql-table-from-python-script
So I used con.close()

How would you " pass the parameters as a second argument to .execute() to guard against SQL-injection attack"

Comment: Like this: `cur.execute(insertstmt, (id, city, state))`. And you would change all your placeholders to the appropriate placeholder for the module you are using. Some use `?`, others use `%s`.

Comment: In either case, it seems that your connection is being terminated prematurely. There may be a configuration you can set for a higher timeout period.

Comment: You might wish to clarify which version, platform of Python you are using and which mysql module. (Is it the same as MySQLdb ?)

Also, try replicating this problem with the simplest example, (eg, just 1 loop of inserts, without the select statements.

Comment: Is your mysql.connector getting grumpy because you aren't closing the cursor before each commit?

Comment: Last does the mysql.connector object come with an autocommit option? That might be more straightforward than doing the commit each time.

Comment: I think it is an network error. I will try to run using Vi editor on the server and will update.. Thanks all..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run the script on Vim on server, it works.